# How to remove default loading indicator in Next.js

Tags: javascript, next.js

I'm using Next.js for a project and when I change the route this default loading shows up in the corner.

[image]

How can I remove it?

Comment: This should only show in development mode, try building and starting your project and it should disappear

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can disable the build loading indicator in the config by setting the `devIndicators.buildActivity` field to `false`.

```js
// next.config.js

module.exports = {
    devIndicators: {
        buildActivity: false
    }
}
```

---

As [pointed out by @Altareos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481301/how-to-remove-default-loading-indicator-in-next-js#comment119274827_67481301), this indicator is only present in development mode and will not appear when building and running the app in production mode.